# AppEngine Stackdriver trace missing datastore rpcs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I have a simple Python app which primarily communicates with Datastore.

Until recently, my app was written in Python 2.7 and used the google.appengine.ext.ndb library.

With that version, I saw plenty of traces involving datastore (e.g. datastore_v3.RunQuery).

I recently upgraded to Python 3.7 and the google.cloud.ndb library.

Now all my traces are just a single entry (my http handler), with no datastore sub-traces as before. Is there a way to fix this?